# How do I get Bootstrap to align one row in the center and one at the bottom?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox, row

I have a section of vh-100, with a container and two rows. I am trying to get one row containing 2 `cols` (headers, image, and dropdown) vertically aligned to the middle of the container, and the other row (an `i` tag) vertically aligned to the bottom. However, this doesn't seem to work. I have tried using Bootstrap's `mt-auto` and `flex-column` but none seem to work, and I am convinced that something is probably wrong with my code, which I append below:

```
  <section class="landing min-vh-100 d-flex align-items-center" id="landing">
<div class="container">

  <div class="row"> #ROW 1 (to be vertically centered)
    <div class="col-md-7 my-auto">
      <h1 class="text-white display-3 mb-4">Text</h1>
      <h3 class="text-white mb-4" id="example">Subtext</h3>
      <div class="btn-group mr-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark rounded-0 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown Menu
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" target="_blank" class="text-white font-weight-bold btn-lg">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 my-auto"><img src="#" class="img-fluid" alt=""></div>
  </div>

  <div class="row mt-auto"> #ROW 2 (to be vertically aligned to bottom)
    <a href="#" class="pt-3 mx-auto"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down text-light"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that the rows are likely centered because of align-items-center on the section tag. I have tried using `my-auto` on Row 1 and `mt-auto` on Row 2, to no avail. I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me with this.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Quite confused with your question here, mind telling me where the dropdown is supposed to be? Row 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Row 1 contains 2 cols (one col has the h1, h3, and dropdown menu, the other col contains the image). My goal is to get the second row with the i tag aligned to the bottom of the container, and the first row aligned to the center. Made the main question and code a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

Make an id for your row and write a css

```
 #row1 .container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

I added container class to your first row and in the second row I added

```
align-text-bottom
```

in your class.

https://jsfiddle.net/Vaulient/j8otzcve/35/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. Apologies for not making it clear in the first place. I have no issue with vertically centering the first col (i.e. with the h1, h2, and dropdown). My issue is with vertically aligning the second row to the bottom of page. I've appended a graphical illustration of my goal to the main question for better clarity.

Comment: I've updated the js fiddle. Hope it solves your issue. I've also updated the answer.

Comment: When editing my answer, I forgot to update the fiddle link. The link is updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `align-middle` and `align-bottom` yet? I think it's short and easy to understand.

Comment: I have tried applying those classes to the rows and unfortunately they do not work.

Comment: Did you apply those classes the right way?

Comment: I removed the ```align-items-center``` from the ```section``` tag as I thought they would conflict with it, and then I applied the ```align-middle``` tag to the first ```row``` and the ```align-bottom``` tag to the second ```row```. Apologies if I haven't understood correctly, as I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Does your parent classes have height? if your classes doesn't have height it'll do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can import in line: class="col-md-7 my-auto" --> class="col-md-12 my-auto justify-content-center" and

class="col-md-5 my-auto" --> class="col-md-12 my-auto justify-content-center"